# Angular router "loadChildren" loading module but router outlet does not render component

Tags: angular

I have a component that is hosted on a remote server:

http://host:port/repository/components/cmpA

In the cmpA folder, the js files are organized in the following way:

```
|-- cmpA
|---- cmpA.module.js
|---- cmpA.component.js
```

In a separate Angular app, this module is loaded via the **Routes** config as follows:

```
var routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'compName',
    loadChildren:'http://host:port/repository/components/cmpA/cmpA.module.js#CmpAModule
  }
  ...
];
```

Then the  with the router link 'compName' is clicked, I see that cmpA.module.js and cmpA.component.js being loaded in the Network tab in Chrome. There are no errors in the console but the markup for the component does not render below the .

Comment: How is it bundled? When you say is a separate app, how separate is it exactly?

Comment: Its a separate NgModule bundled as systemjs modules

Comment: Sorry, I may have misread. It appears you are not bundling it beforehand, which is OK, but what I really meant to ask was is the application one can run on its own? Does it work if you load it from a relative path on the same host? What does the declaration look like and how is it mapped? Also can you add the router configuration for both modules as well as their declarations?